# How to make number of visits without repetition visit?

Tags: php, laravel

How to make number of visits without **repetition** visit ?

> In `PHP` file i using this code :

```
$id='5';
$article = Article::where('id', $id)->first();
$article->number_visit = $article->number_visit + 1;
$article->save();
```

As you see i wrote `number_visit + 1` and add 1 count to `number_visit`

---

But this method is repeated every time (every refresh the page).

How to make number of visits without repetition visit ?

(Thanks For Help)

Comment: what's wrong with this solution ?

Comment: without repetitious visit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check if the visitor has the visitor cookie you set in step 2. If the cookie is present then this is a returning visitor; don't count it. Otherwise this is a new visit and you have to count it.
2. Generate an unique ID for the visit and send the value back to the user in a cookie.

Depending on how do you want to count the visits, either set the cookie to never expire (set an expiration date far in the future) or set it to expire after some time (1 month f.e.).

Be aware that, even if you set the cookie to never expire, for different reasons (use a different browser, reinstall the browser, use private mode  etc.) the visitor might not have the cookie on the next visit and it will be counted as a new visit.